# Adding an event listener to connect the button to the function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const flip = (max) => {
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * max) == 1) {
        return "heads"
    } else 
    return "tails";
}
//console.log(flip(1));

let quater = document.getElementById("coin");

quater.addEventListener("click", flip);
```

```html
<div class="random">
  <button id ="coin" onclick="">flip</button>
  
  
</div>
```

context :Adding an event listener to connect the button to the function

Comment: The code you have provided works. What are you expecting to happen that doesn't?

Comment: When pressing the button, I wanted it to run the function generating a random number of 0 or 1. Which then outputs heads or tails.

Comment: Well for a start you are not displaying the result anywhere. Adding a `console.log()` to the event shows that it fires.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for code that executes a function if a specific element is clicked the following snippet should work (replacing relevant ids and functions).

```
document.getElementById("elementIdHere").addEventListener("click", runThisFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback (flip) will receive a mouse click event as the first parameter. In your case, it would be the `num` param which you use as a number thus making the code not work. You can do this instead

```js
quater.addEventListener("click", event => {
  flip(10);
});
```